# Wrong order of items in pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pg-restore

I have an issue that takes place during restore of postgresql database. During this process creation of extension aws_s3 fails because it depends on plpgsql extension which it seems to be created later on:

[image]

How could this be resolved? Should i reorder items with --use-list option of pg_restore?
Is there another way to solve this? I wouldn't like to exclude anything from pg_dump.

Comment: Add all information as text not as image

Comment: @Jens the display would not be good.

Comment: I'm not sure how you have managed to not have `plpgsql` installed by default in your database. That seems to be the root cause of the error.

Comment: Probably this happens because we use the --clean option in pg_restore.

Comment: Looking at the source code, it seems that dependencies between extensions are not considered by `pg_dump`. If you can compose a complete test case, you could report the problem.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe i'll report this.

Comment: Can you add the `.control` file of the extension to the question? Formatted text, no screen shot, please.

Comment: I am not quite sure I can find it. It is installed in rds PostgreSQL which is managed by Amazon and we don't have access to underlying os files.

Comment: Have you tried using `--create` with `--clean`? That would `DROP` the database and then `CREATE` it again. That would pull in `plpgsql` from the template database before the other objects where added back in.

Comment: It is impossible to reproduce the scenario where pg_restore drops EXTENSION plpgsql at first and then it creates it.